# Missing module error: nvsql.ole

Tags: windows-7, rundll32.exe, rundll

The following error message pops up at 10:29 AM every day, and has done so consistently for about six months:

```
There was a problem starting C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\wupdate\nvsql.ole

The specified module could not be found.
```

I'd like to do at least one of these two things, if not both:

- I would like to get rid of the error message.
- I would like to know what nvsql.ole is and how to get the program/service that depends on it working again. I'm guessing this is a corrupt installation, but I've been completely unable to determine what it is that has been corrupted.

Comment: The message itself tells you whats missing.  You have a task setup to run at 10:29AM 7 days a week.

Answer (score 2):

In general, when you are receiving mysterious error messages, and especially in your case where you can't find any information by googling the file path in the error message, there are some lower level steps you can take to attempt to diagnose the problem.

Here is what I would do in your shoes, in order of difficulty / expertise required:

1. Go to Start -> Run, or alternatively, type [<kbd>Windows Key</kbd>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_key) + <kbd>r</kbd>, and then type `taskschd.msc` and click OK.

   - In the "Task Scheduler" that pops up, look under the "Active Tasks" pane for any tasks that are scheduled to run at or around the time you receive the message.
   - Keep in mind that the program that's scheduled to run may have to execute an action for several seconds/minutes/hours before it displays that error message, so if you don't see 10:29 AM, don't assume that the task isn't there.
   - Look for *almost anything* that runs on a daily basis around-ish that time.
   - Once you identify something interesting-looking, double-click on the entry for it in the Active Tasks pane, and observe the properties of the task.
   - Under the "Actions" pane, you may see an action such as "Start a program", with a path given to the program that's being invoked. Once you get the name of this executable, you can either google the .exe name, or look at other files that reside in the same folder as the executable and attempt to determine what it is.
   - The executable name is very likely to have *some* documentation on it in Google, unless it's an in-house thing that your company developed.
2. If Task Scheduler doesn't have anything in it that looks relevant, you can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) from SysInternals (now part of Microsoft) to get more information about exactly what's going on on your system. Process Monitor requires administrative privileges to be maximally useful.

   - Download and install it, obtain admin rights from your system administrator if you're in a corporate IT environment, then start Process Monitor around 10:25 AM or so, and let it capture stuff (file reads/writes, etc).
   - Try not to do **anything** with your computer while Process Monitor is running. Don't browse the web, don't edit documents, don't check email, don't do anything! Close as many background programs as you possibly can. This will minimize the amount of "noise" you get when Process Monitor captures system activity, thus making it easier for you to find the real culprit when 10:29 AM rolls around.
   - Examine the file and registry accesses that occur exactly at 10:29 AM. You may see that a program is being launched, and that files from the `\AppData\Roaming\wupdate` folder are being accessed. It will tell you the name of the process that accessed (or attempted to access) that file. You can then google the name of the process, or ask Process Monitor to tell you the file path of the process, and then see if the folder name gives any details about the company that developed the program.
   - You can also right-click on the executable itself in Windows Explorer, go to Properties, then look at the details and see if the executable has any information about what the program is -- company, program name, etc.

Once you've used one of these methods to identify what the program is, then you can start to take some meaningful steps to fixing it:

- If you're sure you know what the program is, you can uninstall and reinstall the program to see if it fixes it. Or, if you don't need the program, just remove it.
- If you don't know what the program is, and you don't want it to keep running, you can remove its Task Scheduler entry (if one exists; it's not absolutely required that any periodically running program must use Task Scheduler; it could be using anything to do its timing...) or try to delete the program / .exe that launches at 10:29 AM.
- If you can identify the vendor and product name of the program, you can try contacting the vendor, quoting the error message and asking if there's a way to resolve it.
- You can try renaming the entire "wupdate" folder in your Roaming folder to something else. This will make the program fail to find that folder at all. Some programs, if the data in there isn't critical to your work, will just re-create the folder and any requisite files inside... maybe if it's just some kind of a cache, you don't care, and the program will stop complaining?
- As a last-ditch effort, you can try reinstalling Windows, then install your programs one by one, and if the message starts occurring again, then you know that one of the programs you normally use is causing it.

These steps can be difficult or impossible in a corporate IT environment where you don't have admin rights, so if that is the case, tread lightly and be sure to work on this in cooperation with your local IT staff, instead of trying to get around them or go behind their back.